# Show Minimized Windows in Mission Control (El Capitan)

Tags: macos, mission-control

This is a possible dupe of [Can I get Mission Control to show minimized windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18127/can-i-get-mission-control-to-show-minimized-windows), but I wanted to get an update on this issue since its now 2015.

What I really want is to have Mission Control for non-minimized apps (just like the current Mission Control), but then an optional Mission Control which shows all current windows, even the minimized ones.

Is this second option possible? Or is there some third party app that mimics the functionality of Mission Control to achieve this?

Comment: Hidden or minimized windows are not shown in mission control, this is a big mistake, Apple never admits its mistake.